# PostgreSQL or Mysql for a basic app?

Tags: mysql, postgresql

I have created an app that needs many joins and the ratio of reading-writing is 3-1. I replaced Mysql with Postgres to test the project but I didn’t found any difference in performance.

My main concerns about Postgres:

1. I use pgbouncer and according to docs each new connection needs 10mb
   min instead of light threads that Mysql uses.
2. find it more complex for an app that doesn’t needs - handles big
   data like statistics etc.. so the tables like jsonb, array etc are
   never used
3. the ratio of concurrent connections between Mysql and Postgres for a small instance (1GB Ram-1vCPU) has
   ratio ~ 4-1 (eg. 80 connections Mysql vs 20 Postgres)

In other words, if I want to scale the db in the future, I need a 3x db instance in order Postgres to handle same amount of connections as mysql.

Please correct me if I’m wrong and I would like your experience migrating from Mysql to Postgres.

Ps I use Mysql 8 and Postgres 14, so I would like the answers to be based on these versions (not Mysql 5.6 etc..)

Comment: I find your 2. and 3. incomprehensible, but 1. is plain wrong: a connection to pgBouncer is very cheap.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Can you provide more info about memory consumption per connection on Postgres? About 2, i mean that Postgres has to offer very much and maybe it is an overkill for a project that doesn't focus on big table statistics data etc.

Comment: I don't understand 2 and 3 either. But I personally would never choose MySQL over Postgres. Starting a process on modern OS isn't really that much more expensive than starting a new thread.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe About 3, in many cloud providers eg. Digital Ocean, if you pick a basic instance 1GB RAM - 1vCPU for Postgres, they offer via PGbouncer, 25 connections. In Mysql with the same setup, they offer 75.

Comment: A connection to pgBouncer is just a network connection. That doesn't consume 10MB. Perhaps you are talking about backend connections, but you have only a few of them if you have a pool.

Comment: So you want a recommendation for a database **and** a suitable cloud hosting offering?

Comment: No I don't want a cloud hosting offering, I have noticed this availability across many cloud providers between MySQL and PostgreSQL. So my question is why there is this difference? Is Postgres heavier or it doesn't need so much connection availability if you use Pgbouncer?